# How to use apply or vapply in a dataset column with a multiple parameter function

Tags: r, function, lapply

My dataset is called data and I have a column called time that contains time in mm:ss format. I also wrote a function functime(var1,var2).

I would like ultimately to use apply or vapply and have var2 set to a constant (lets say var2 = 6) and var1 to be each value of the column data$time.

Something like:

If

```
data$time <- c("10:10","11:00", "09:30"), when I do vapply(), I would like to get a 

data$output <-c(functime(data$time[1],6),functime(data$time[2],6),functime(data$time[3],6))
```

which in this example is the same as

```
data$output <- c(functime("10:10",6),functime("11:00",6),functime("09:30",6))
```

My lame attempt to that is something like:

```
vapply(data$time,functime,var2 = 6,FUN.VALUE = 1)
```

The documentation for vapply says it should be :vapply(x,fun,fun.value)

I am confused on how to "say to vapply" that I want to take as its first argument all rows of the data$time column, have a fixed second argument that I will define it as 6.

Ultimately I would like to add my data$output in the original dataset using a mutate.

Edit: (Include lines of data and function)

```
data$id <- c(9,6,5763,4)

data$time <- c("5:06","5:06","5:11","5:08")

data$city <-c("Kyle","Oklahoma","Monterey","Austin")
```

The function is:

```
    calctime <- function(racePace, raceDistance){

  # racePace is the per unit pace in mm:ss - character
  # raceDistance is the total race distance - numeric
  # Pace and race distance must use same units (km or mi or whatever)

  # Seconds to character time function
  CharMinSec <- function(sec){
    outMin <- floor(sec/60)
   outSec <- ((sec/60)-outMin)*60
    if(outSec==0 | round(outSec)<10){
      outChar <- paste0(outMin,":0",round(outSec))
    } else {
      outChar <- paste(outMin,round(outSec),sep=":")
    }
    outChar
  }

  paceMinSec <- as.numeric(strsplit(racePace,':')[[1]])
  paceSec <- paceMinSec[1]*60+ paceMinSec[2]
  raceMin <- floor(paceSec*raceDistance/60)
  raceSec <- ((paceSec*raceDistance/60)-raceMin)*60
  raceTime <- CharMinSec(raceMin*60+raceSec)
  list(Seconds=raceSec)
}

# Example of 4:15/km for a half-marathon


calctime("4:15",21.097494)
```

Comment: Could you post your function code and some lines of your data?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the answer. The function is not mine (for plagiarism issues), I adjusted one I found online that was doing what I wanted.

Comment: Done, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
calcTime <- function(pace,distance){ 
  return (lubridate::period_to_seconds(lubridate::ms(pace)) * distance)
}


pace <- c("10:10","11:00", "09:30")
vapply(pace,calcTime,6,FUN.VALUE = 1)

## 10:10 11:00 09:30 
## 36960 39960 34560 

d <- tibble::as_tibble(list(pace = pace))
dplyr::mutate(d, raceSeconds = calcTime(pace,6))

## A tibble: 3 x 2
##    pace   raceSeconds
##    <chr>  <dbl>
##  1 10:10  36960
##  2 11:00  39960
##  3 09:30  34560
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to change 2 things, but your `vapply` call was right.

In the function, I changed the last line so it returns a value instead of a list with one value

```
calctime <- function(racePace, raceDistance){

  # racePace is the per unit pace in mm:ss - character
  # raceDistance is the total race distance - numeric
  # Pace and race distance must use same units (km or mi or whatever)

  # Seconds to character time function
  CharMinSec <- function(sec){
    outMin <- floor(sec/60)
    outSec <- ((sec/60)-outMin)*60
    if(outSec==0 | round(outSec)<10){
      outChar <- paste0(outMin,":0",round(outSec))
    } else {
      outChar <- paste(outMin,round(outSec),sep=":")
    }
    outChar
  }

  paceMinSec <- as.numeric(strsplit(racePace,':')[[1]])
  paceSec <- paceMinSec[1]*60+ paceMinSec[2]
  raceMin <- floor(paceSec*raceDistance/60)
  raceSec <- ((paceSec*raceDistance/60)-raceMin)*60
  raceTime <- CharMinSec(raceMin*60+raceSec)
  raceSec
}
```

Now that the list returns a value, the `vapply()` works, but in my case I had to force  the time column to be a character

```
data = data.frame(
  id = c(9,6,5763,4),
  time = c("5:06","5:06","5:11","5:08"),
  city = c("Kyle","Oklahoma","Monterey","Austin")
)

data$time = as.character(data$time)

data$output = vapply(data$time,calctime,raceDistance = 6,FUN.VALUE=1) #works fine
```

Comment: Thank you, any idea why I get : "Error in vapply(data$time, calctime, raceDistance = 6,  : 
  values must be type 'double',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'list'"

Comment: Did you change the function's last line? But Bruce's answer is much better anyway

Comment: Ah, ok I see..Thanks! It doesn't matter, I am trying to learn from both answers. They likely do what I couldn't!